# Who discovered the rule for the definite integration of a function summed with its inverse function across a fixed limit?

Tags: calculus

I saw this rule used in an MIT integration bee that gives a result for the definite integral of a function summed with its inverse across a fixed limit:

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x) + f^{-1}(x)dx = x_{2}^{2} -x_{1}^{2}$$

i tried googling but i don't know the given name of the rule if it has one, so I did not find anything.

Who invented/discovered this rule and if that isn't known then who is the earliest known person to have used it? thanks

Comment: I think you need more hypotheses.  There is something called "Young's inequality".  https://brilliant.org/wiki/youngs-inequality/

Comment: The equality you gave doesn't hold for $f(x) = 2x.$ That said, see the Wikipedia page [Integral of inverse functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions). Two additional references NOT cited there are: [Boas/Marcus 1974](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2319570) and [Dean 1987](https://www.irishmathsoc.org/bull19/bull19_82-83.pdf).

Comment: What does it mean "across a fixed limit"? What is really assumed about $f,x_1,x_2$? That $f(x_j)=x_j, j=1,2$?